# Could different schemas of microdata cause conflict between Google and Meta Pixel?

Tags: seo

I'm trying to add structured data to our products page to improve SEO. We have Open Graph microdata set up for Meta Pixel, which in theory should be usable for Google as well,but Google's [Rich Results Test](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results) Doesn't seem to detect it.It does detect Schema.org format though,but so does  [Facebook Microdata Debugger](https://business.facebook.com/ads/microdata/debug).So, currently I have Google's debugger detecting only Schema.org format and FB debugger detecting BOTH Open Graph and Schema.org formats.

My question is: If we were to deploy in our current situation, which microdata format would Meta Pixel prioritize? Does the number of fields matter in this case(We have about 12 for Meta Pixel and around 10 for Google)? Is there a way to specify which format should Meta Pixel use in case there is more than 1 provided?

The docs for Google have so far been sort of confusing and some resources even contradict each other.

Comment: I don't know which Facebook prioritises but I've always just stuck with schema.org and it has worked well. The exception to this is when using Open Graph to define how a post would appear on Twitter/FB. Always have those elements in OG format.